# Connection log for Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, firewall

I need to make a system to system connection to an Azure SQL Database.

To enable connection to Azure SQL Database, I need to open the firewall to the connecting systems IP.

I think I have the wrong IP address to the system that is trying to connect to my Azure SQL Database - but I have no way of verifying it.

**How do I see which IP that has failed connecting to an Azure SQL Database.**

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you,  can you please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)?This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I see which IP that has failed connecting to an Azure SQL Database?**

The answer is no, we can not get the IP which failed connecting to the Azure SQL database.

What we can get is the sum/count of Failed Connections :
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Please enable Auditing on Azure SQL Database.

If your database already had Auditing enabled, then visit the dashboard.

[image]

After that click on "Azure SQL - Security Insights".

[image]

Now choose "Distribution by success".

[image]